# When using a Raku grammar, can one limit parsing time?

Tags: parsing, grammar, raku

---

The following Raku program defines a grammar `Parser` then attempts to use it to parse the string `baa`.  However, program execution takes too long.  Is there a way to limit the amount of execution time devoted to parsing so that parsing can be deemed to have exceeded the desired limit and *timed out* ?

---

```
grammar Parser
  {
  token  TOP  { <S> }
  token S { '' | <S> <S> | 'a' <S> 'b' | <S> 'a' | 'b' <S> 'b' }
  }

sub MAIN()
  {
  say Parser.parse( 'baa' ).Bool ; # Would like True, False, or Timeout
  } # end sub MAIN
```

---

Also, might there be plans to have [Raku](https://www.raku.org) implement the [Adaptive LL(*)](https://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf) parsing of [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org)?  Version 4.11.1 of ANTLR has code generation targets including Java, Python, and others, but not Raku.

---

Comment: It's important to notice that it doesn't take to long. It's got a built in infinite loop. As `S` can match `''` or `<S> <S>` it will just keep making longer and longer matches of blank strings.

Pretty sure it'll do that with any strong not just 'baa'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to stop parsing other, other than by exiting the process.  If that is ok with your situation, then you could do something like:

```
start {
    sleep 10;   # however much time you want it to give
    note "Sorry, it took to long";
    exit 1;
}
```

If that is not an option, there are several variations on the above theme, with e.g. putting the grammar parsing into a `start` block and wait for the promise to be kept, or broken.